# Writing text in between to strings on a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

```
def getlink():
    with open('findlink.txt') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        copy = False
        for line in infile:
            if "](" in line.strip():
                copy = True
            if copy:
                outfile.write(line)
            if ")" in line.strip():
                copy = False
        print("extractlink written.")


def part3():
    with open ('findlink.txt', 'w') as findlink:
        findlink.write("[Testing](Test)") 
        print("findlink written and closed.")
        getlink()

def run_bot():
    getlink() #Already have findlink.txt written
```

When `part3()` is activated, the text is written to findlink.txt as expected, but when `getlink()` is activated, the extractlink.txt is never written to.

I've gathered my current code from a post back in 2013/2016, does anyone have any ideas why this may not be working?

The current goal is to have "Test" from findlink copied to extractlink.txt, not the entire line.

Comment: I edited your code to fix indentation and you don't need to close the files when you have them wrapped in a `with` statement

Comment: Hello, I don't think `line.strip() == "]("` is ever true (strip removes whitespace in the left and right of the string) Maybe you mean `"](" in line.strip()`?

Comment: Yes @solarc, I've adjusted the thread, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Someone edited your post to fix this, but you should understand that it is unnecessary to explicitly close a file when using a "with" statement AKA a **context manager**, because they handle this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [tutorial][1] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

`line.strip("text")` removes `text` from the string.

So when you call line.strip() == "](" you are comparing line.strip("") with "](" which is always false unless the input line was just "](". So this condition is not really doing anything.

To get the Test from the file, I used line.find() which gives the index of the character in the string.

```
print line.find("](")
print line.find(")")
print line[line.find("](")+2: line.find(")")]
```

output:

```
8
14
Test
```

So then you could just do this for getlink().

```
def getlink():
    with open('findlink.txt') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line[line.find("](")+2: line.find(")")])
            print("extractlink written.")
        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
```

extractlink.txt:

```
Test
```

This is just one simple solution. You could implement it differently, but you may want to use line.find() instead of line.strip().

Answer (score 0):

A simple parser :

```
def getlink():
    with open('findlink.txt') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            begin = line.find("](")+2
            end = line.find(")")
            if 0 <= begin < end:
                   outfile.write(line[begin:end]+'\n')
```